# Opening existing grails project

Tags: grails

I have a simple grails(2.0.3) application with a couple of domain models, controllers and services for them. After I saved it and try to run on another machine I get some strange behaviour.

Generated controller links on the index page look correct, but being clicked redirect me to localhost:8080/appname/appname with 404 instead of localhost:8080/appname/controller/action.

But when I try to manually recreate a model with "grails generate-domain-class", generate a controller and create a service class it works fine. It seems like some project data is lost after moving it, or perhaps it is stored somewhere outside my project folder.

What do I need to do to save my working project at 1st machine and reopen it at 2nd one? My application is created without using any IDE, just command line and text editor.

**EDIT**

After trying to reproduce this behaviour without posting all the unnecessary code got the same without moving project to another machine.

When I create a controller that uses injected service(after reading [this](http://www.kromhouts.net/blog/grails/grails-service-and-controller-interface/)):

```
class BookController {

    def bookService

    def index() {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    def list() {
        def result = bookService.list(params)
        if(!result.error) {
            return [ bookInstanceList: result.bookInstanceList,
                bookInstanceTotal: result.bookInstanceTotal ]
        }
        flash.message = g.message(code: result.error.code, args: result.error.args)
        redirect( url: resource(dir:'') )
    }
}
```

and generate views I try to access generated controller url at index page and get localhost:8080/appname/appname with 404. No error messages displayed in grails console.

Comment: If it isn't much, could you give the reproduction steps and/or the code? Would like to try this out and check.

Comment: Finally I`ve managed to solve this. The last string in controller method caused such a strange behaviour. So moving application from one machine to another caused a trouble indirectly. On the 1st machine database tables where not empty and application did not rich that line. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I've found two things help when having grails issues after moving a project to a different machine. First is to run

```
grails upgrade
```

When it prompts you if you want to upgrade the project say yes. Doing this will rewrite any missing configuration files you may not have moved over. Second is to run

```
grails clean
```

This will remove any compiled classes you may have moved over from your old system to your new one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately that did not solve the problem. 
I`ve already tried this solution after reading [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/nondeterministic-behavior-of-g-link-and-g-createLink-td1341333.html) post. That looks very similar, but even after both `grails upgrade` and `grails clean` I`m still getting this "double appname mode".